# check a condition for a <td> value in a table

Tags: jquery

I have this table tag html

```
<table class="table  dataTable" id="customer_details_table" aria-describedby="sample_1_info" style="display: table;">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Customer Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Contact No.</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="odd gradeX">
      <tr>
         <td><label class="radio"><input type="radio" onclick="UpdateButtonTest(this);" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1"></label></td>
         <td width="20%">kiran</td>
         <td width="25%">XXXXXXX</td>
         <td width="20%">7654321987</td>
         <td width="20%">venkatrajkiran@yahoo.com</td>
         <td width="10%" align="center"><span class="label label-success">Active</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><label class="radio"><input type="radio" onclick="UpdateButtonTest(this);" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1"></label></td>
         <td width="20%">kiran</td>
         <td width="25%">XXXXXXX</td>
         <td width="20%">9701429843</td>
         <td width="20%">s@g.com</td>
         <td width="10%" align="center"><span class="label label-inverse">DeActive</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to find out if in the table there is any value by name DeActive in the action values

I have tried out this way

```
  function find() {

        var header = document.getElementById("customer_details_table").getElementsByTagName("th");
        for (var j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
        if (header[j].innerHTML == "DeActive") 
          alert("Found");
        }

}
```

Could anybody please tell me how to find out if any Action has got value as DeActive ??

http://jsfiddle.net/kz2j2jjy/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through each td and compare:

```
fucntion find(){
     $("#customer_details_table tr td span").each(function(){
         var texttocheck = $(this).html();
         if(texttocheck == "DeActive"){
         alert("found");
         }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, pretty simple:

```
var tds = $("table#customer_details_table tr td:contains('DeActive')");
```

Comment: Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kz2j2jjy/2/ , i am getting object , object what doees this mean ?? can i get true or false ??

Comment: @PreethiJain -- It's a jQuery object - so you can run methods on it. `tds.text()` - `tds.each(function() alert($(this).text() })` - etc.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged jQuery, but since you posted pure JavaScript, here's a JS solution:

```js
function find() {
  var tb= document.getElementById('customer_details_table'),
      header = tb.getElementsByTagName('th'),
      cell,
      j,
      k;
  
  for(j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
    if (header[j].innerText === 'Action') {
      for(k = 1 ; k < tb.rows.length ; k++) {
        cell = tb.rows[k].cells[j]
        if(cell.innerText==='DeActive') {
          cell.style.background= 'orange';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

find();
```

```html
<table class="table  dataTable" id="customer_details_table" aria-describedby="sample_1_info" style="display: table;">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Customer Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Contact No.</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="odd gradeX">
      <tr>
         <td><label class="radio"><input type="radio" onclick="UpdateButtonTest(this);" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1"></label></td>
         <td width="20%">kiran</td>
         <td width="25%">XXXXXXX</td>
         <td width="20%">7654321987</td>
         <td width="20%">venkatrajkiran@yahoo.com</td>
         <td width="10%" align="center"><span class="label label-success">Active</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><label class="radio"><input type="radio" onclick="UpdateButtonTest(this);" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1"></label></td>
         <td width="20%">kiran</td>
         <td width="25%">XXXXXXX</td>
         <td width="20%">9701429843</td>
         <td width="20%">s@g.com</td>
         <td width="10%" align="center"><span class="label label-inverse">DeActive</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should use jQuery, it makes your life much easier.

Take a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kz2j2jjy/3/

The function within `$()` is called as soon as the browser is ready. The `each()` loop just iterates over all rows, searchs for the `span.label`-Element and checks the content of the Element. If the content is `DeActive`, the loop breaks (`return false;`) and alerts.

Additionally there was a small error in your JSFiddle: The `find()` function was never called.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#customer_details_table').find('tr:has(td:last-child:contains("DeActive"))').each(function() {
  var index = $(this).closest('table').find('tr:has(td)').index( this ) + 1;
  alert( 'found in row: ' + index );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table  dataTable" id="customer_details_table" aria-describedby="sample_1_info" style="display: table;">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Customer Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Contact No.</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="odd gradeX">
      <tr>
         <td><label class="radio"><input type="radio" onclick="UpdateButtonTest(this);" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1"></label></td>
         <td width="20%">kiran</td>
         <td width="25%">XXXXXXX</td>
         <td width="20%">7654321987</td>
         <td width="20%">venkatrajkiran@yahoo.com</td>
         <td width="10%" align="center"><span class="label label-success">Active</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><label class="radio"><input type="radio" onclick="UpdateButtonTest(this);" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1"></label></td>
         <td width="20%">kiran</td>
         <td width="25%">XXXXXXX</td>
         <td width="20%">9701429843</td>
         <td width="20%">s@g.com</td>
         <td width="10%" align="center"><span class="label label-inverse">DeActive</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```